# Accessing Website and Reading HTML -> With signing in. | Using Powershell

Tags: html, authentication, download, powershell-3.0

Im trying to read out the HTML Code of Web-Side. Its where the Logs of my server are stored in, thus I have to use my credentials.

[Thats's how the login looks like, but I just can't get it to work. Powershell always states, that the user authentification is wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJYmj.png)

when I try this:

```
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName ##### 
Start-Process http://######/spi/#####/etc/log/mlog/ -Credential $credential
```

I always get: Unknown Username or wrong Password.

[This is the code for showing and Downloading the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nveiI.png)

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: The codes work, when I try it with www.msn.com or other websides